# PyCharm (Python 3.x) modify a class without re-running the script

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, ide, pycharm

I am using PyCharm Pro 2018 and just made the switch to it recently (from Spyder).

The first part of my script involves loading a lot of data and takes about 1-2 minutes. On completion or error of the script I get a python console with all the current variables where I can investigate.

Now if I would like to change a method/function and run it again WITHOUT completely restarting the script, how can I do that?

Here some pseudocode:

```
class FetchData():
    ...

class ParseData():
    ...
    def subroutine1(self, ...):
        ...

data = FetchData(...) # takes a long time
parser = ParseData(data,...)
parser.subroutine1(...)
```

After running this code and getting an error in subroutine1, I get a console and can look at "data" and "parser" (as well as any other variables). Is it possible to modify subroutine1 and manually re-run that method in the console "parser.subroutine1(...)" with the changed method and "data" still intact?

If not, or in general, what would be the best practice to code on subroutine1 without having to constantly reload "data = FetchData(...)"?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways I have gone about this:

1.) Use a Jupyter Notebook. One of the biggest features/strengths of Notebooks is exactly this ability; to encapsulate parts of your code from each other and if you get an error in later cells/blocks of code, it will not make you start from scratch.

2.) Pickle your data's results and refer to that instead. Python's builtin pickle module has the ability to create "pickle" files which can hold almost any piece of data you have created in your long-running subroutine. So split your code into 2 files, the long-running/data creating one will only create the data and pickle it; run it only when you need to update the data inside the pickle file. The 2nd/subsequent routines you want to run on your data are in a python file that opens/reads the pickle file (which is a very fast action) and then works on the previously stored data inside it.

Answer (score 0):

something close to what you asked for:

1. Execute in the debugging mode
2. Go to the line that involves calling your `subroutine1`
3. Execute that line in Debugger Console (eg highlighting it followed by Alt+Shift+E)
4. if you don't like the result:

   1. change `subroutine1`, then fully highlight it (from `def subroutine1(self, ...):` to the very last line)
   2. do Alt+Shift+E (executing it in Debugger Console)
   3. Then again execute the line that involves calling your `subroutine1`, that will give you the result according to your updated subroutine1, etc